# R-squared for training set is way larger then the R-squared for testing set. What can that mean for the regression model?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

```
Training Metrics:
R squared: 0.8099510921986353

Testing Metrics:
R squared: 0.17368322884835363
```

This is the result. I tried optimizing the data but the result does not change by much? What must be wrong with the model or data? What can this difference in value mean for the model and data being used?

Answer (score -1):

Probably your model is overfitted for your training dataset. You could change the hyperparameters or try different resampling methods (e.g. try lower k for cross-validation).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33674985)